# SQL joining without common keys

Tags: sql, db2

If I have a table with the following atributes:

A: id, race, key1
B: key1, driving_id
C: driving_id, fines

why would it be possible for us to have the following queries:

```
select A.id, A.race, B.key1, B.driving_id, C.fines
from A 
left join B on A.key1=B.key1
left join C on B.driving_id= C.driving_id
```

even though there are no common keys for A and C in the last line of the SQL query?

Comment: Yes, of course.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Why: Transitive property.  B lets you get from A to C by translating key1 to driving_ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that you have written is parsed as:

```
select A.id, A.race, B.key1, B.driving_id, C.fines
from (A left join
      B
      on A.key1 = B.key1
     ) left join
     C 
     on B.driving_id = C.driving_id;
```

That is, `C` is -- logically -- being joined to the result of `A` and `B`.  Any keys from those tables would be valid.

Although your original query is the preferable way to write it, you could also write:

```
select ab.id, ab.race, ab.key1, ab.driving_id, C.fines
from (select . . .  -- whatever columns you need
      from A left join
           B
           on A.key1 = B.key1
     ) ab left join
     C 
     on ab.driving_id = C.driving_id;
```

The three versions are all equivalent, but the last one may help you better understand what is going on with joins between multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I was confused initially when I read that SQL is a declarative language and not a procedural one. Would we be able to implement the joins if we switch the 3rd line with the 4th line? Sorry for asking this as I am unable to access my database now.

Comment: @Anthony . . . Assuming you are referring to your version of the query, then "no".  You would get an error to the effect that the table alias `c` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing sample data from the three tables, we might not know for sure in the query makes any sense or would even run.  Assuming it does run, then there should be nothing wrong with the join logic.  For example, it is perfectly possible for table `B` to have a key `key1` which relates to the `A` table, while at the same time having another key `driving_id` which relates to the `C` table.  Note that either of these keys (but not both) could be a primary key in the `B` table, and if not then each key would be a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (tableA), and the matched records from the right table (tableB). Furthermore, Similarly it returns all records from the result of first set, and the matched records from the right table (tableC). The result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.

So A & C have a link through table B.